# The subcollection of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb R)$ with nonzero diagonal entries is a subgroup?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be the subcollection of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb R)$ such that for every $A\in G$ each diagonal entry of $A$ is nonzero.

How do I prove that $G$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb R)$?

Any hints?

Comment: Do you mean **all** the diagonal entries are non-zero or at least one entry on the diagonal is non-zero?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a subgroup?

Comment: @Don all the diagonals

Comment: @Alex Yes, the binary operation here is the usual matrix multiplication. I have a trouble with showing that $G$ is closed under the operation and contains inverse elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1&-1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1&1\\1&\!\!-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\;\;0&2\\-2&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Not a subgroup...

Comment: Nice, you were quicker!

Comment: Much quicker, @mookid ! About 17 seconds...hehe. :)

Comment: @Don It's weird since it's said "G" is a subgroup in the answer. (Fraleigh p.55)

Comment: @John.p, you misread: exercise 9 in page 55, Fraleigh, mentions **diagonal matrices** with no zeros in their diagonal...! Exercise 10 talks of upper-triangular matrices with no zeros...You missed quite an important and basic piece of info.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be wrong: look at rotations

$$
\left( \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1  \\
  -1 & 1 
 \end{pmatrix}\right)
^2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1  \\
  -1 & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}
$$